# Why does a carbon pile work as a rheostat?

Tags: electricity

This afternoon I opened a sewing machine pedal, and inside it I found a ceramic material containing lots of small and thin black disks. I didn't expect that. I've searched on the Internet and I've found a device called **carbon pile** that could be the same device I found (write **carbon pile disks** on Google Images or [try this link](https://www.google.com/search?q=carbon%20pile%20disks&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjG48nv18foAhVD_hQKHS50AAwQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=carbon%20pile%20disks&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1CYE1iYE2DIFmgAcAB4AIABcYgBcZIBAzAuMZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1n&sclient=img&ei=gcaEXoafEsP8U67ogWA&bih=667&biw=1366) to see the disks).

It seems that there isn't much information about this device. The only information I've found is that the carbon pile resistance is dependent on the pressure exerted along the pile.

So, now I know why the carbon pile is employed as a rheostat or as a potentiometer. But I don't understand why a pile made of carbon disks varies its resistance depending on the pressure. Any idea?

Perhaps this is a very basic question, but I can't think of any simple explanation.

Comment: Interesting question: never seen one of those. I suspect that $R \propto \frac{1}{P}$ because better contact between the discs makes flow of electrons easier.

Comment: Graphite may be chosen here because its conductivity is mediocre but it's a very stable material, even at elevated temperature.

Comment: Gert's comment is spot-on. By increasing the pressure one lowers the contact resistance between the discs. I've seen such devices used in early radio sets to vary the temperatures of the valve filaments! And the same principle is used in the (obsolete) carbon microphone: the pressure variation in the sound wave changes the resistance between the walls of a capsule of carbon granules, and if the capsule is put in series with a battery and a (distant) earpiece one has telephony!

Comment: Unless there are three wires going in, the pile is acting as a variable resistor, not a potentiometer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you press a pile of carbon particles together to form a pill-like disc, you will find that the electrical resistance of the pressed disc is higher than that of a similarly-sized disc of solid carbon. This is because those particles of carbon are not all in good contact with one another.

If you then compress that disc, you mash the particles together into better physica contact with one another, building better electrical contact between them, and the resistance of the disc drops. That resistance change can be used as a control signal.

If you mill some soft rubber into the carbon particles before pressing them into discs, then you get a disc that wants to return to its original dimensions after you release the pressure, yielding a pressure-sensitive variable resistor.

If you instead loosely pack the carbon granules into the space between two flexible metal foil discs separated by an insulator, you can make this pressure-sensitive resistance effect so sensitive that the resulting device serves as a *microphone*, as used in old-style telephones and radio transmitters.

If you form the rubber-loaded carbon into a tiny pointed cone and press its tip into another metal contact, you obtain an electrical switch whose resistance varies smoothly from infinity when the contacts are not touching to a very low value when the cone and the contact are firmly pressed together. This is the principle of the *anti-induction* or *noiseless switch* as used in audio circuits.